# Use the value from a dataframe to lookup in another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to use a value which is in a df column (df1) as an index to lookup in another df (df2).

I reached a solution using apply and lambda function:

```py
max_edad = int(df2.iloc[:,0].max() - 1) #The value will be 116
df1['Vivos(t)'] = df1['fecha_ord'].apply(lambda x: df2.loc[int(x), 'lx_1970'] * (1 - (x % 1)) + df2.loc[int(x) + 1,'lx_1970'] * (x % 1) if x < max_edad else 0)
```

However I am running it in a huge database and it is so slow (although it works).

Do you know how can I run it in a different way to get it faster?

Here are some examples of my dataframes:

**df1**

| t | fecha | Factor_desc | fecha_ord |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2016-04-01 | 1.000000 | 45.325120 |
| 1 | 2016-05-01 | 0.996339 | 45.407255 |
| 2 | 2016-06-01 | 0.992691 | 45.492129 |
| 3 | 2016-07-01 | 0.989056 | 45.574264 |
| 4 | 2016-08-01 | 0.985435 | 45.659138 |
| 5 | 2016-09-01 | 0.981827 | 45.744011 |
| 6 | 2016-10-01 | 0.978232 | 45.826146 |
| 7 | 2016-11-01 | 0.974650 | 45.911020 |
| 8 | 2016-12-01 | 0.971082 | 45.993155 |
| 9 | 2017-01-01 | 0.967526 | 46.078029 |
| 10 | 2017-02-01 | 0.963984 | 46.162902 |
| 11 | 2017-03-01 | 0.960454 | 46.239562 |
| 12 | 2017-04-01 | 0.956938 | 46.324435 |
| 13 | 2017-05-01 | 0.953434 | 46.406571 |
| 14 | 2017-06-01 | 0.949943 | 46.491444 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1390 | 2132-02-01 | 0.057234 | 161.158111 |
| 1391 | 2132-03-01 | 0.057163 | 161.237509 |
| 1392 | 2132-04-01 | 0.057093 | 161.322382 |

**df2**

| edad | lx_1970 |
| --- | --- |
| 0.0 | 1.000000 |
| 1.0 | 9.909948 |
| 2.0 | 9.901297 |
| 3.0 | 9.896776 |
| 4.0 | 9.892829 |
| 5.0 | 9.889542 |
| 6.0 | 9.886405 |
| ... | ... |
| 41.0 | 9.577991 |
| 42.0 | 9.565103 |
| 43.0 | 9.551536 |
| 44.0 | 9.537515 |
| 45.0 | 9.522749 |
| 46.0 | 9.507039 |
| ... | ... |
| 116.0 | 0 |

I expect the following df as a result:

**df3**

| t | fecha | Factor_desc | fecha_ord | Vivos(t) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2016-04-01 | 1.000000 | 45.325120 | 9.517642 |
| 1 | 2016-05-01 | 0.996339 | 45.407255 | 9.516351 |
| 2 | 2016-06-01 | 0.992691 | 45.492129 | 9.515018 |
| 3 | 2016-07-01 | 0.989056 | 45.574264 | 9.513728 |
| 4 | 2016-08-01 | 0.985435 | 45.659138 | 9.512394 |
| 5 | 2016-09-01 | 0.981827 | 45.744011 | 9.511061 |
| 6 | 2016-10-01 | 0.978232 | 45.826146 | 9.509770 |
| 7 | 2016-11-01 | 0.974650 | 45.911020 | 9.508437 |
| 8 | 2016-12-01 | 0.971082 | 45.993155 | 9.507147 |
| 9 | 2017-01-01 | 0.967526 | 46.078029 | 9.505715 |
| 10 | 2017-02-01 | 0.963984 | 46.162902 | 9.504274 |
| 11 | 2017-03-01 | 0.960454 | 46.239562 | 9.502972 |
| 12 | 2017-04-01 | 0.956938 | 46.324435 | 9.501532 |
| 13 | 2017-05-01 | 0.953434 | 46.406571 | 9.500137 |
| 14 | 2017-06-01 | 0.949943 | 46.491444 | 9.498696 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1390 | 2132-02-01 | 0.057234 | 161.158111 | 0.0 |
| 1391 | 2132-03-01 | 0.057163 | 161.237509 | 0.0 |
| 1392 | 2132-04-01 | 0.057093 | 161.322382 | 0.0 |

Thanks you so much!

Comment: please define acttable?

Comment: Sorry my mistake! I put it wrong after I edited these lines of code, now it is fixed and fine. Thanks you!

Comment: The second line of code posted is incorrect.  Please ensure the entire statement is included.

Comment: Sorry it was my first time posting and I made some typos. Now it is fixed, thanks you!

Comment: The second line of your code doesn't execute when applied to your sample data.  Do you expect DF! and df2 to be the same length?

Comment: Can yo explain what is the logic behind the computation of Vivos(t)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to break the calculation into several steps:

```
df1['fecha_ord_int'] = df1['fecha_ord'].astype(int)
df1['fecha_ord_dec'] = df1['fecha_ord'] % 1
df2['lx_1970_next'] = df2['lx_1970'].shift(-1)

df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_on='fecha_ord_int', right_on='edad')

# now do the calculation you want
# you can drop the columns you don't want later
```

hopefully that helps

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer!

Thanks of your idea I used the join option with the index instead of merge (in order to run it faster):

```python
df1 = df1.set_index('fecha_ord_int')
df1 = df1.join(df2[['lx_1970','lx_1970_next']], how='left')
df1['Vivos(t)']=df1['lx_1970'].values*(1-df1['fecha_ord_dec'].values)+df1['lx_1970_next'].values*df1['fecha_ord_dec'].values

```

Comment: glad it helped, those calculation will all be vectorized, and we should see a speed increase